# How to get extension from string filename in Erlang

Tags: erlang

How do I get the file extension from a filename-string in Erlang, even if there may be a dot in the filename itself, e.g.: Filename This.Great.Image.jpg?

Cheers

Comment: Get the last index of '.' And make substring starting from that index.

Answer (score 5):

The `filename` module in the stdlib has an `extension/1` function which works the way you want. See http://erlang.org/doc/man/filename.html#extension-1

Answer (score 4):

Another solution (which is also a great mental exercise) is to use recursion and pattern matching based on the fact that [Erlang strings are just lists of codepoints](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#lists).

```
-module(fileutils).
-export([ext/1]).

ext(Filename) -> ext(Filename, "").

ext([46 | Rest], _)  -> ext(Rest, Rest);   % "." == 46
ext([_ | Rest], Acc) -> ext(Rest, Acc);
ext(_, Acc)          -> Acc.
```

Then `fileutils:ext("my.coolest.file.jpg")` will get you "jpg".

**EDIT**: As Dogbert has suggested in the comment, you can use `$.` to get the codepoint of `.` instead of hardcoding `46`.

Comment: Tip: you can use `$.` instead of `46` to get the codepoint of the character `.`.